# How to filter properties/collections out from representers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-roar

For example, I have a representer looking like:

```
module AccountRepresenter

  include Roar::Representer::JSON
  include Roar::Representer::Feature::Hypermedia

  property :id
  property :name

  collection :assets, :extend => AssetRepresenter, :class => Asset
end
```

In controller I use it as:

```
respond_with @accounts, represent_with: AccountsRepresenter
```

For another action I don't want `collection :assets` to be presented. I tried

```
respond_with @accounts, represent_with: AccountsRepresenter, exclude: :assets
```

But it doesn't work. How should I pass argument into representers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Roar gem uses Representable underneath (https://github.com/apotonick/representable#conditions). You can do the following things to have conditional functionality:

```
respond_with @accounts, represent_with: AccountsRepresenter, exclude: [:assets]
```

Then

```
module AccountRepresenter

  include Roar::Representer::JSON
  include Roar::Representer::Feature::Hypermedia

  property :id
  property :name

  collection :assets, extend: AssetRepresenter, if: lambda { |opts| !opts[:exclude].includes?(:assets)] }
end
```